# Is C# Enumerable.Reverse().Aggregate(initval, func) a true Right Fold?

Tags: c#-3.0, folding

Wikipedia says that [`Reverse().Aggregate(initval, func)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29) is a Right Fold. This sounds like it is not true, but rather a cheap cop out... Can anyone comment on this issue? Does C# have right folds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take definition of right fold and check whether `Reverse().Aggregate(initval, func)` fits into it.

Definition:

> Combining the first element with the results of combining the rest is called a right fold

So if you want to calc the sum of `(1, 2, 3)`. If you just `Aggregate` the evaluation will be `(1 + 2) + 3`. If you `Reverse().Aggregate` then it will be `(3 + 2) + 1`, which perfectly fits the definition.

The question might be is it efficient because `Reverse` is expensive operation, but functionally it is perfect right fold.

Comment: @Andrey: Could you elaborate bit more on the efficiency? How is it possible to implement right fold more efficiently? I was thinking about it a lot and I only came up with a solution using recursion (which might cause stack overflows on large sequences).

Comment: @tomp if you have `List` or other data structure that allows traversal from back to forward then the cheapest option will be to just have loop from tail to head. Anyway I don't see any points of having right fold if you have operator/function that are 1) pure 2) associative 3) commutative. `a + (b + c) == (a + b) + c` so unless some very exotic cases I don't see any point of doing right fold instead of left fold.

Comment: @Andrey: If the data structure allows traversal from the back to forward (implements ICollection), the Reverse function should be implemented in a way efficient to the data structure. See by yourself: http://referencesource-beta.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#e247ee4147678571

Comment: @Andrey: The question is not about the point of having right fold though. I agree with you that there are not many real-world scenarios for usage of a function like that. But also note that not all functions are associative and commutative (take an ordinary division for instead). As pointed out in comment by *Jörg W Mittag*, your answer **is wrong** for every `func` which is not commutative. To be correct for both commutative and non-commutative functions, you would have to flip the function too, i.e. `(a, b) => func(b, a)`.

Comment: @tomp you are right and `Reverse().Aggregate(initval, (acc, val) => func(val, acc))` solves the problem making it truly right fold

Answer (score 0):

`Aggregate` is a true left fold. Aggregating a reversed list has the same semantics as a complete (non-lazy) right fold on any reversible list.